# How to increase the amount of object properties printed to console in chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

This code produces the following output.

```
console.debug('values:', getValues())
```

As you can see, the object's properties are trimmed and require manual interaction.

[image]

> ### Is it possible to print all object's own properties inline right away?

Note that I don't want to use `JSON.stringify`, because the output is, well, a string.

[image]

Comment: These limits are [hardcoded](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:v8/src/inspector/value-mirror.cc;l=901;drc=da6ef73266f6110abc5e788457f0e8f9257dd5b6?sq=package:chromium).

Comment: You can use custom formatters, see the [top links for more info](https://www.google.com/search?q=devtools+custom+formatter).

Comment: I will just put this here so that I or someone can later look at it [Set up development of DevTools](https://youtu.be/TWqFbKpV5Oc)